# Why should one take part in elections?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges, election

Why should one take part in elections?

Do I get any reputation for that?

There should be some profit; like, how would it help me after elections?

Comment: Must **everything** on S.E be about rep?

Comment: then we should also pay team of StackExchange for such a great database of information.

Comment: No of course not. Just want to know how it helps me personally.Because after electon no one remembers the votes and their needs.

Comment: Well you're at it, feature-request to all the governments everywhere and everytime to pay you to vote.

Comment: Profit is, you select the persons who will moderate you. They are people who will guide you or help you when you have some problems. It is just like choosing your your governor in local elections; you do not get any reputation or money in them too.

Comment: Almost everything you do on Stack Exchange is public - and that holds for moderators too. If you believe a moderator is not acting in accordance with his/her election promises, you can point it out on Meta. Just bring proof, and be polite and professional about it.

Comment: If you need reputation or badges to take part (and the reasons given in the answers don't matter to you), then don't take part - we don't need (or want) people who'll take part just for taking part without much consideration for who they're actually voting for - the ideal is that anyone voting will take a significant amount of time looking at each candidate to determine those best suited to moderate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya you get badges but you don't get any reputation though. But seriously this kind of question hurts a bit to all voters who give votes for the development of this community. I would answer this, as you should not see any profit in voting. But if you choose the right person of course the elected member will look at all problems and ethical laws of the site and indirectly you will benefit. So do vote in all elections. And remember you have an option whom to choose so don't neglect. 
I feel only a candidate with sufficient reputation should be allowed to vote,and a candidate with less reputation should be given time to know why exactly they are here for.

Answer (score 14):

No. You take part in elections since you believe it's good for the workings of the site.

Besides, you get *badges* for participating. One of them is silver (Constituent).

That ought to be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

That question is very insolent, but actually it's an important aspect that should be answered.

What's the **profit** from taking part in elections?

You have **influence** on who becomes moderator. Moderators handle flags and have binding votes, so they **shape topic** of the site more than the other members of community. How the topic for the site is defined, is something that influence directly you in the moment you're asking the question.

--
To ilustrate the importance of voting, consider you ask question which is immediately closed by community moderator. You ask on Meta **why?** and you receive a comment: "Have you voted? If not, you've sent a signal you don't care who has the power over your posts".

Comment: If I received a comment like that, I'd just think the person who left it was kind of dumb. Whether the person whose question was closed by a diamond moderator voted for that moderator, against that moderator, or not at all, is completely irrelevant.